# In XCode, how can I edit a file that is going into the bundle in a post build step without editing the original?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, post-build-event

We have a variety of YAML configuration files in our iPhone project and we would like to remove all comments from the files as well as add a signature at the bottom. Is there an easy or standard way to do bundle modifications prior to application signing?

Comment: I have not done this in particular, but you might look up Xcode "build rules" which is how Xcode processes each file as it's moving it into your bundle.

Comment: I'll give this a look and see what I find.